# Apache mod compile error: apxs mod_antiloris.c

Tags: apache, apache-modules, apxs2

Try to install mod_antiloris. Getting compile error, when running the below command:

```
apxs -a -i -c mod_antiloris.c
```

Compile Error:

> mod_antiloris.c:126:37: error: **'conn_rec' has no member named
>   'remote_ip'**
>        apr_cpystrn(ws_record->client, c->remote_ip, sizeof(ws_record->client));
>
> mod_antiloris.c:133:10: warning: passing argument 1 of
>   'ap_get_scoreboard_worker' makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]
>             ws_record = ap_get_scoreboard_worker(i, j);

- Apache version: Apache/2.4.6 (SLES Expanded Support platform)
- O/S Redhat 7.4

Any advise please?

Thanks
Nic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the module is outdated: [according to doxygen](https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/structconn__rec.html) the existing fields are either `client_ip` or `remote_host`.

Edit: someone posted a patch [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=20560#20560).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Having a battle to find 0.5.1 or greater version.
Where can it be downloaded from? Could only find 0.4, but is the one with compile errors

Comment: Did you try https://gist.github.com/NewEraCracker/e545f0dcf64ba816d49b ?
Compiles for me.